# How to disable click event after element's drag and drop in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, animation, dom, click

Actually I bind animation states on the element on which I applied CDKdrag and drop. It automatically triggers animation state when an element is dropped. How to disable animation on drop? How to differentiate animation click event and drop element event

codes-----
**typescript:**

```
//animation

 trigger("changebarChartSize",[  
            state("ZoomBarChart",
                   style({ 
                          transform: "scaleX(1.7) scaleY(1.3) translate(335px,60px)",
                          border: "2px solid grey",
                          background:"linear-gradient(to top right, rgb(233, 232, 232), white)" })),

      state('Barfade',
             style({
                     position:'fixed', 
                     marginTop: '0',                                    
                     transform: 'translateX(10px)',
                     background:'linear-gradient(to top right, rgb(233, 232, 232), white)',    
                     width: '12vw',
                     height: '19vh',
                     border: '1px solid grey'
                    })),    
                    transition('*=>ZoomBarChart', animate("1300ms")),
                    transition('*=> Barfade', animate("2000ms")),
                   
            ]), 
//function
  barfunction()
  {
           this.ZoomBarChart= true;
           this.Barfade=false;
  }
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div cdkDrag class="barchart one">  
 <div class="mychart1"
      (click)="barfunction()"
      [@changebarChartSize]= "ZoomBarChart?'ZoomBarChart':'Barfade'">                  
      <ng-template  [ngIf]="Barfade"  [ngIfElse]="BarelseBlock">
      <div class="handle bardrag" cdkDragHandle>
      <svg width="24px" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
          <path d="M10 9h4V6h3l-5-5-5 5h3v3zm-1 1H6V7l-5 5 5 5v-3h3v-4zm14 2l- 
                   5-5v3h-3v4h3v3l5-5zm-9 3h-4v3H7l5 5 5-5h-3v-3z"></path>
          <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
      </svg>
      </div>       
      <div class="icon" style="margin-top: 20px; font-size: 40px;">
           <mat-icon [inline]="true">equalizer</mat-icon>
      </div>  
      <h4 style=" margin: 0;
                  margin-Top:5px ;
                  padding: 0; 
                  line-height:1.1; 
                  font-weight: normal;
                  font-size:0.98em ;
                  text-align: center; 
                  vertical-align: middle;">
                   title
      </h4>          
      </ng-template> 
      <ng-template #BarelseBlock>
      <div class="handle bardrag" cdkDragHandle>
      <svg width="24px" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
          <path d="M10 9h4V6h3l-5-5-5 5h3v3zm-1 1H6V7l-5 5 5 5v-3h3v-4zm14 2l- 
                   5-5v3h-3v4h3v3l5-5zm-9 3h-4v3H7l5 5 5-5h-3v-3z"></path>
          <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
      </svg>
      </div>
      <h4>  title </h4>
      <canvas baseChart 
              [chartType]="barChartType">
        </canvas> 
   </ng-template>
  </div> 
  </div>
```